# Cannot sign in my android application outside India

Tags: android, gmail

I have developed one [Mobile Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.secuiritylite.smslite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zZWN1aXJpdHlsaXRlLnNtc2xpdGUiXQ..) application and in that application, there is an option of forgot password (which is app password). So in case of forgot password, I am sending his/her password through "MY GMAIL ACCOUNT my@gmail.com" to his/her account (user@gmail.com).
Now, the issue comes here : Since I have made this id in India and if someone who is USA (for example) has installed my app, and is clicking the forgot password option. Now when my app tries to sign in into gmail with my@gmail.com, google is preventing the sign in, coz this id was made in India and is being accessed outside of India (USA).

So please any idea So that I can avoid this issue.....
Any Help appreciated..!!!

Comment: How do you send the email? (what library do you use?)

Comment: I am using this package org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse;

Comment: through this i am sending mail by hard coding user name and password.

Comment: Hmm isn't JSSE used for SSL and such? I don't know anything about sending emails with it.